# How to prune out two directories in find command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, find

I have the following command:

```
$ find /mnt/DCS_01 /mnt/DCS_02  \
  -name Transit -prune -o .Trashes -prune -o -type f
```

I am trying to prune out the `Transit` and `.Trashes` directores, but am having some difficulty with the syntax. What would be the proper command here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parentheses to specify multiple args --

```
$ find /mnt/DCS_01 /mnt/DCS_02  \
  \( -name Transit -o -name .Trashes \) -prune -o -type f
```

Comment: The above is executed as `...\) -a -prune -o -type f`. The reason it works is that `-a`  has higher precedence than `-o` (and the parentheses have higher precedence than both)